# How to algebraically represent digits of a number?

Tags: notation

I need, in proper and widely accepted mathematical form, to algebraically represent each of all the digits in any given integer. Here is my mathematically illiterate way of conveying this idea to you: $$a_{1}a_{2}\dots a_{n-1}a_{n}\quad\text{where}\quad a_{1}\quad\text{would match first digit of given integer,}\quad a_{2}\quad\text{would match second, and so on}$$

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The usual thing is to put a bar over the number, such as $\overline {a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}a_n}$.  Still, I'd say it's not absolutely standard notation so it's worth explaining what you mean when you use it.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @lulu, $(a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n-1},a_{n})$

Comment: Well, you can use any notation you want so long as you define it clearly.

Comment: But it's a bad idea to use non-standard notation without a clear definition. As to your notation, what order are you reading in?  That is, does the $3-$ tuple $(1,2,3)$ refer to the number $123$ or the number $321$?

Comment: That's why clear definitions matter.  If you want it that way, then i suggest putting the indices in reverse order, so $(a_n,a_{n-1},\cdots, a_1,a_0)\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^na_i10^i$.

Comment: @lulu, thank you. What does that arrow mean? I think it has something to do with set notation? Is it because tuple is similar to a set?

Comment: It's functional notation, I mean that your $n-$tuple is associated, by your process, to that that sum.  It's read as "maps to".

Comment: Well, I don't think this is likely to be standard notation.  To be sure;  it's fine to use it if it suits some application you have in mind.  Just be sure to define it clearly when you do.

Comment: Yes, the answer of @RobertIsrael is the standard notation; same as the notation I mentioned in my first comment (well, you have to get clear on the indices).

Comment: @lulu, thank you for clarifying (it helps consideerably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k^{th}$ digit from the right (origin $0$) is

$$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor\bmod 10.$$

E.g., $n=20519$, $k=2$,

$$\frac{20519}{10^2}=205.19,\\\left\lfloor205.19\right\rfloor=205,\\205\bmod10=5.$$

The number of digits is

$$\left\lfloor\log_{10}n\right\rfloor+1.$$

---

Note the $k$ can very well be negative.

Comment: @bp2017: oyu can guess by looking at the example.

Comment: @bp2017: yep. Sometimes written with square brackets $[\ ]$.

Comment: @bp2017: replace $10$ by the base.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to number starting from the end, so your number is 
$$ x = \overline{ a_n a_{n-1} \ldots a_0} = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k 10^k$$ where 
$$ \lfloor x/10^k \rfloor \equiv a_k \mod 10 $$
This is, of course, for positive integers.

Comment: You can write the integer $a_1a_2a_3...a_{n-1}a_n$ (base 10) as $a_1\times 10^{n-2}+ a_2\times 10^{n-3}+ a_3\times 10^{n-4}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ a_{n-1}\times 10+ a_n$.